# call_user_func_array() errors after migrating site with InstantWP

Tags: migration, fatal-error, callbacks

I am setting up a WordPress site locally from a site online. I downloaded the files and database. I used InstantWP to set up the site. I imported the database and moved over the proper files for the local site. When I go to the site, I get these errors:

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'wp_maybe_load_embeds' not found or invalid function name in C:\Users\William\Desktop\InstantWP_4.5\iwpserver\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\plugin.php on line 525
>
> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'rest_cookie_collect_status' not found or invalid function name in C:\Users\William\Desktop\InstantWP_4.5\iwpserver\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\plugin.php on line 525
>
> Fatal error: Class 'WP_User' not found in C:\Users\William\Desktop\InstantWP_4.5\iwpserver\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\pluggable.php on line 38

Can someone explain to me what these are and how I can fix them?

Comment: What version of Wordpress is this? Are the versions of PHP on InstantWP and your server the same?

Comment: It is Wordpress 4.6, PHP is 5.3.2. for both.

Comment: PHP 5.3.2 is old and technically no longer supported by Wordpress. That being said I don't think that is the issue.

I was just typing in what Ethan answered below so I'd start here.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a migration issue. Did you made sure you've updated the link of your local WordPress install to your new URL?

Changing the `home` and `siteurl` in your `wp_options` table is not enough unfortunately. You will still have your post content with your non-localhost URL (`http://web.site`) causing your website to not display properly on your localhost.

You should have the `wp_options` table on your localhost copy. Everything should be intact. To make sure exported your database from your live site correctly, please follow these [quick instructions provided by WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Backing_Up_Your_Database#Quick_backup_process).

Once you've downloaded and imported your database to your localhost. Follow these steps:

1. Go and download [Interconnect IT's Database Search & Replace Script here](https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB/archive/master.zip)
2. Unzip the file and drop the folder in your **localhost** where your WordPress is installed (the root) and rename the folder to **`replace`** ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9Ga5.png))
3. Navigate to the new folder you created in your browser (ex: `http://localhost/wordpress/replace`) and [you will see the search/replace tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbED1.png)
4. It should be pretty self-explanatory up to this point: enter your old URL in the **`search for…`** field and the new URL in the **`replace with…`** field

You can click the *dry run* button under *actions* to see what it will be replacing before you execute the script. Once you're done be sure to remove the `/replace/` folder.

Comment: Hi Ethan.  Thanks for the suggestion.  I ran the query.  Site url and home were changed but I'm still getting the errors.  Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Ethan, I got it to work.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad to hear William, be sure to upvote and click the checkbox to let users know this answer helped you.

Comment: @WilliamHodge Please let us know what you did to get it working, if it wasn't what was in this post - it will help other users :)

Comment: @WilliamHodge did my solution help?

Comment: The issue was actually with the database. I had to bring it down and install again and it worked out. Thanks for the help from everyone.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was actually with the database.  I had to bring it down and install again and it worked out.  Thanks for the help from everyone.